# How to bind formula for Excel in RDLC report

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, report, reporting, rdlc

[image]

**Now after exporting this in excel, when i give input in propose salary i will get a percentage ammount. Is there any way to bind exec formula from Rdlc report?**

Answer (score 0):

There is formula field in report.By click formula field you write the formula.
write formula which you have to calculate.

Comment: When I write a formula it will be in the rdlc as well as in the excel. But I want a way to bind formula only for excel. After exporting excel report,when I give some input there it will calculate on it by the binding formula.